# With Serde JSON why does "{c:[{}]}" cause a heap allocation when deserializing into a RawValue struct?

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to understand how heap allocations work in Serde JSON.

Why does the following code make one heap allocation? I am expecting no allocations as the value of `c` is a borrowed `serde_json::value::RawValue` using `#[serde(borrow)].

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    #[serde(borrow)]
    c: &'a serde_json::value::RawValue,
}

fn main() {
    let msg = r#"{"c":[{}]}"#;

    // One unexpected allocation here.
    serde_json::from_str::<MyStruct>(msg).unwrap();

}
```

Note using `{"c":[2, 3]}` for example instead of `{"c":[{}]}` will result in no allocations.

How can I make it so there are zero allocations when deserializing into `MyStruct`?

[Rust playground link.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5edd4c92ab663f6980c1b8133641354d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid the allocations. The parser needs to allocate some memory on the heap because JSON objects and arrays can nest arbitrarily deeply, and it needs to keep track of what type of value it's currently parsing.

I [modified your program](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1a2451497bc74526f22213ec85e8a428) to panic on the first heap allocation that happens during parsing (because I'm too lazy to debug and there's no debugger on the playground). The backtrace shows where the heap allocation is coming from. The key frame is this one:

```
  14: serde_json::de::Deserializer<R>::ignore_value
             at ./.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/serde_json-1.0.69/src/de.rs:1049:21
```

You can be sure that your `MyStruct` won't point to heap allocated memory, because your struct contains a shared reference and not an owned value (and the input is a static string). In order for `c` to refer to heap allocated memory, `serde_json` would have to [leak](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.leak) it (and it doesn't do that; it would be pretty bad if every parse could leak memory!).

Answer (score 1):

The allocation is internal to `serde_json` and will be freed before returning. There is an internal scratch area which can require allocations ([source](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/379412b13875cfb2e440937c4508944d48ee6c96/src/de.rs#L1049)).

The README of `serde_json` also mentions the fact that it relies on alloc support, so allocations are not unexpected:

> As long as there is a memory allocator, it is possible to use serde_json without the rest of the Rust standard library.

If you need to work without allocations you can instead try [serde-json-core](https://github.com/rust-embedded-community/serde-json-core) which is also mentioned in that README.